# How to run the Curl command deom bash script

Tags: linux, curl

I have below script to run a curl command from Linux host, which takes user inputs and runs but its not turning successful while same command manually succeeds.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Constants
api_key="Thdshd760Jd"
api_url="https://execute-api.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive;done"

# User input
read -p "Enter projectName: " projectName
read -p "Enter siteName: " siteName
read -p "Enter emailAddress: " emailAddress
read -p "Enter the path to the file containing disk names: " disk_file

# Read disk names from the file and create a comma-separated string
disks=$(awk '{printf "\"%s\", ", $1}' "$disk_file" | sed 's/, $//')

# Create JSON payload in Bash
json_payload="'{\"projectName\": \"$projectName\", \"siteName\": \"$siteName\", \"disks\": [$disks], \"emailAddress\": \"$emailAddress\"}'"

# Make the API request using curl
curl -vv  -X POST -H "x-api-key: $api_key" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$json_payload" $api_url

echo 'curl -vv -X POST -H "x-api-key: '$api_key'" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '$json_payload' '$api_url''
```

Below how i am executing it ..

```
$ ./curl_api_call.sh
Enter projectName: my_disk001
Enter siteName: JLDC
Enter emailAddress: labtest@example.com
Enter the path to the file containing disk names: demo_file
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
{"message": "Invalid request body"}
curl -vvvvvv -X POST -H "x-api-key: Thdshd760Jd" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"projectName": "my_disk001", "siteName": "JLDC", "disks": ["my_disk001"], "emailAddress": "labtest@example.com"}' https://execute-api.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive
```

**even doing like giving same  error:**

```
for i in `cat` ; do curl -vvvvvv -X POST -H "x-api-key: Thdshd760Jd" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"projectName": "$i", "siteName": "JLDC", "disks": ["$i"], "emailAddress": "labtest@example.com"}' https://execute-api.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive;done
```

please guide me on how this can be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes in the JSON assignment are wrong.

```
# Create JSON payload in Bash
json_payload="'{\"projectName\": \"$projectName\", \"siteName\": \"$siteName\", \"disks\": [$disks], \"emailAddress\": \"$emailAddress\"}'"
#             ^                                                                                                                          ^
```

Similarly, in the `for` loop attempt, the single quotes prevent the variables from being interpolated.

```
for i in `cat` ; do
    curl -vvvvvv -X POST -H "x-api-key: Thdshd760Jd" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d '{"projectName": "$i", "siteName": "JLDC", "disks": ["$i"], "emailAddress": "labtest@example.com"}' https://execute-api.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive;done
#          ^                                                                                                 ^
```

Try this:

```
json_payload="{\"projectName\": \"$projectName\", \"siteName\": \"$siteName\", \"disks\": [$disks], \"emailAddress\": \"$emailAddress\"}"
```

and similarly

```
while read -r i; do
    curl -vvvvvv -X POST -H "x-api-key: Thdshd760Jd" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -d "{\"projectName\": \"$i\", \"siteName\": \"JLDC\", \"disks\": [\"$i\"], \"emailAddress\": \"labtest@example.com\"}" \
          https://execute-api.amazonaws.com/prod/v1/archive;done
done
```

(Also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) .)

Comment: Using while loop giving an error `{"message": "Internal server error"}Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.`

Comment: I haven't debugged the other parts; I obviously cannot know what a valid request looks like without more information.